# How do I limit Isotopes' filtered results?

Tags: jquery, filtering, limit, jquery-isotope

I've had a look around SO but couldn't find anything close to what I want (still learning).

Scenario

I'm using http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ to filter rss data.

I am pulling 6 different rss feeds with 10 posts each, which amounts to 60 in total.

I have a 6 filters (combinational type) for each set of feeds, meaning I can choose to filter more than one at a time.

Because of the amount of data I have, I only want to display the first 15 of the latest on the page.

As I understand it, Isotope needs to see the whole data before it can filter properly.

So, the question is how can I only display 15, no matter how many combination of filters I choose?

I can't use ':nth-child(-n+15)', as that only picks out what is laid out in the DOM, not the positioned elements. Any pointers?

pseudocode:

```
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.isotope({
    filter : comboFilter,
    itemSelector : '.element',

  }, function displayOnly15($elem) {

    //how do I display only 15?

  })
});
```

Am I missing an important step/process before or after?

Figured out that I could do something like:

```
var $filtered = $container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms;
```

Then use something like:

```
$keep = $filtered.slice(0,14);
$remove = $filtered.filter(function(i){
    return i > 14;
});
```

But calling:

```
$container
          .isotope( 'insert', $keep)
          .isotope( 'remove', $remove );
```

...after, refreshes the layout twice in quick succession.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that last bit of code, I think you want to use addItems ([Found on this page](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html)):

Use it like this:

```
$container.isotope( 'addItems', elements )
```

It works like insert, but it doesn't lay the items out. So then this:

```
$container
      .isotope( 'addItems', $keep)
      .isotope( 'remove', $remove );
```

Will do the swap, and then do one layout.

In terms of only showing 15 items, you can always just `hide()` any extra items. Doing anything else would require custom javascript to create and/or swap the actual data.

If you go that direction, something a bit more heavy than Isotope and jQuery might be helpful (like angular, knockout, etc).